# Django rest framework field with custom save/restore logic

Tags: django-rest-framework

How can I create a Django rest framework read-write field with custom save/restore logic? I'm using DRF 3.5.4 and Django 1.8.

Something like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    # username is a field in the backing model, no problemo
    username = serializers.CharField()

    # type is not an actual model field, but reflects whether the user has 
    # Django permission "foo" set. I.e. "normal" = no permission, "silly" = 
    # permission is set.
    type = serializers.ChoiceField(["normal", "silly"])
```

In other words: when creating a user, if `type == "silly"`, permission "foo" is set for him and not set if type is "normal". And when retrieving user, `type == "silly"` if the user has permission "foo" set, and "normal" if not.

No update of the user is allowed/needed, but I'm interested in knowing how to apply this to update too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Didn't test it but this approach should work. Just for reading you can user [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). But this type of fields are read-only. To have `type` in `validated_data` you need to use custom field.

```python
from rest_framework import serializers   

class UserTypeField(serializers.CharField):

    def get_attribute(self, instance):
        return 'silly' if instance.has_perm('foo') else 'normal'


def set_permission_by_type(instance, user_type):
    if user_type == 'silly':
        instance.add_perm('foo')
    elif user_type == 'normal':
        instance.remove_perm('foo')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = UserTypeField()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_type = validated_data.pop('type', None)
        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        if user_type:
            set_permission_by_type(instance, user_type)
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_type = validated_data.pop('type', None)
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        if user_type:
            set_permission_by_type(instance, user_type)
        return instance
```

Comment: Just had to change `user_type = validated_data.get('type')` to `user_type = validated_data.pop('type')` and move it before `super().create()`, otherwise crashes inside `User.objects.create()` with `TypeError: 'type' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`. Works like a charm, thanks!